# Записать результат работы приложения в файл

Tags: c#, filestream

Скажите, существует ли способ скопировать все данные из консоли, по окончанию работы приложения в файл?

Да, можно конечно каждый раз, когда что-то выводится на консоль параллельно записывать в файл, но можно ли одним махом конечной результат из консоли переписать в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой Log4Net.

Она умеет писать одновременно в файл и консоль, а так же в любое другое место(Например, БД), имеет гибкие настройки, поддержку многопоточности.

И не нужно изобретать велосипед.

Можно так же сделать вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Trace.Listeners.Clear();

    TextWriterTraceListener twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
    twtl.Name = "TextLogger";
    twtl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.ThreadId | TraceOptions.DateTime;

    ConsoleTraceListener ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false);
    ctl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime;

    Trace.Listeners.Add(twtl);
    Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;

    Trace.WriteLine("The first line to be in the logfile and on the console.");
}
```

Взято отсюда:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420429/mirroring-console-output-to-a-file

Comment: Да-да, нужно и там и там.

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин Вроде, поправил.